# Prime number reader

Tags: c

This is my first post here, so it might not look too good. I'm trying to write a code to read if a number is a prime number. I was looking for some help, since this is my code right now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
  int getal;
  int i;

  printf("Voor een getal in: ");
  scanf("%/n", &getal);


  for(i = 2; i <= getal / 2; ++i)
  {
    if(getal % i == 0)
    {
      printf("Dit is een priemgetal");
      system("PAUSE");
    }
    else 
    {
      printf("Dit is geen priemgetal");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The problem with it is that it wont show me the printf at the end.

Comment: `scanf("%/n", &getal);` does not look very good to me.

Comment: Note that the code is C++ and not C (due to one of the header files included).

Comment: What does the program actually *do* (you have only stated what it does *not* do) when you ran it using a debugger?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If you are going to use header names to make up your judgement, then you could say it is a mix of C and C++ due to <stdio.h>

Comment: I did not notice that before, the amount of information we've gotten has been quite low. But if I take the iostream file out, my system doesn't work anymore

Comment: Your `scanf()` is wrong. `scanf("%d", &getal);`

Comment: The program lets me put in a number and then ends the run

Comment: Use `scanf("%d", &getal)` to read an integer. Also, I'm not sure what language is that, but I'm guessing got your conditions reversed.

Comment: This will also print a message every time you check an `i` that isn't a divisor. Set a flag, `prime = 1`, and change it to zero during the loop. In the end, check this flag.

Comment: "If `i` is a divisor, say 'it is prime' and stop. If `i` is not a divisor, say 'it's not prime' and keep looking for divisors." This is a very odd algorithm.

Comment: It seems like I've found my problem, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple problems:

- there is no need for the C++ `<iostream>` include file
- conversely, you should include `<stdlib.h>` that defines the `system()` function.
- the format string `scanf("%/n", &getal);` is incorrect. Use `"%d"` instead.
- the message should not be printed for every divisor tried, you should use an extra variable for the prime test and print the message at the end.
- finish your output with a newline.
- You are programming in an IDE with a poor execution framework. Your program shows the output, but closes the window immediately unless you request user input. Move the `system("PAUSE");` to the end of the `main` function.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int getal;
    int i;
    int isprime;

    printf("Voor een getal in: ");
    scanf("%d", &getal);

    isprime = 1;
    for (i = 2; i <= getal / 2; ++i) {
        if (getal % i == 0) {
            isprime = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isprime) {
        printf("Dit is een priemgetal\n");
    } else {
        printf("Dit is geen priemgetal\n");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Misterguppie:  you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.